# Copy utuntu.iso to pc then intall it by a usb

Tags: boot

As the title, how to install ubuntu previously copied in windows7 by a usb booter.
Thanks.

Comment: plz explain briefly.

Comment: Welcome to AskUbuntu, unfortunately I cannot understand the question. Can you please edit it to make it more explicit?

Answer (score 0):

You can

1. download USB installer from
   [pendrivelinux.com](http://www.pendrivelinux.com/).
2. Select the
   Ubuntu ISO that you have on your Windows partition and create a
   LiveUSB of Ubuntu.

Please refer to detailed instructions [here](http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop/create-a-usb-stick-on-windows).